# Installing a .deb file manually?

Tags: apt

`apt-get install gitosis --fix-missing` on my Linode still leads to a 404

```
(Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gitosis/gitosis_0.2+20080825-2_all.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
)
```

. The correct file location seems to be `http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gitosis/gitosis_0.2+20090917-11_all.deb`

Is there any way I can install this without apt-get, or point apt-get in the right direction somehow?

Several other packages on my Debian Linode also point to 404, both from command line and virtualmin.

EDIT: Machine details Debian 5.0 64bit (Latest 2.6 (2.6.39.1-x86_64-linode19))

EDIT2 My sources list

```
# main repo
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free

deb     http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile  lenny/volatile  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile  lenny/volatile  main contrib non-free

# contrib & non-free repos
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib non-free
#deb http://security.debian.org/debian/ lenny/updates contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian/ lenny/updates contrib non-free

deb http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/debian/ virtualmin-lenny main
deb http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/debian/ virtualmin-universal main
```

Comment: Try an `apt-get update` before and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: That leads to several 404s as well

Comment: Then post your `sources.list`.

Comment: How old is this machine? Has the release passed into the great void of unsupported legacy?   If not you need to spend a few minutes and clean up your apt sources - an `apt-get update` shouldn't be producing 404 errors for a current, supported release...

Comment: How do I get my sources.list and find out the "age" of the machine? Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: As of March 24, Debian 5.0 (Lenny) has moved into archive.debian.org. Most Debian mirrors don't carry Lenny any more, and worse, Debian no longer provides security patches for it.

Answer (score 4):

1. `wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gitosis/gitosis_0.2+20090917-11_all.deb`
2. `dpkg -i gitosis_0.2+20090917-11_all.deb`
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: If you're still set on gitosis. This will make you profitable.

Answer (score 0):

Since gitosis is no longer updated and is being deprecated, I suggest installing [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) right away. (It's also better at the job.)

Comment: apt-get install gitolite tells me E: Couldn't find package gitolite

Comment: Probably not in the repo, clone the git repo and install it that way would the best

Comment: No.  The best way would be to install [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) and build a .deb file, then install that.

Comment: Smart, didn't know of that way. Much better.